# Cannot access Ajax Rating from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have this html markup:

```
 <div id="profil_rating_container">
    <div id="profil_rating">
        <div id="pr">
            <h2 id="rating" class="profil_rating_title">Hodnocení&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblAddRating" runat="server"><span><a href="#add_rating" title="Přidat hodnocení"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a></span></asp:Label></h2>           
            <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <ajaxToolkit:Rating ID="FinalRating" runat="server" MaxRating="5" ReadOnly="true" StarCssClass="ratingStar" WaitingStarCssClass="savedRatingStar" FilledStarCssClass="mainFilledRatingStar"  EmptyStarCssClass="mainEmptyRatingStar" />  
            <br />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="RatinSqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SportovniPlanetaCS %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [RatingText], [RatingCount], [Name] FROM [rating] WHERE ([ProfileId] = @ProfileId) AND ([RatingText] IS NOT NULL)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ProfileId" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:Repeater ID="RatingRepeater" DataSourceID="RatinSqlDataSource" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RatingRepeater_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <h4><a href="#"><asp:Literal ID="RatingName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /></a></h4>
                    <p class="p_rating"><asp:Literal ID="RatingText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RatingText") %>'></asp:Literal></p>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRating" runat="server" Text="Uživatel zatím nemá žádné hodnocení." Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And when I am accesing Ajax Control Toolkit Rating from code behind like this: `FinalRating.CurrentRating = cmdRating.ExecuteScalar` it underline `FinalRating` with error text: *'Final Rating' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.*

I don't know why this is happening. I have the same code in other 5 pages and it is working finec, but in this one page it isn't. Also when I add new page and add Ajax Rating, I cannot access it from code behind. The rating control isn't in any data component like repeater or datalist. Can this be solved by `FindControl`? If yes, how exactly?

Does anyone know, what is causing this problem? Thanks for answer.

Comment: If you look at the aspx.designer.vb class for your aspx page, does it contain FinalRating?

Comment: No. When I tried to add it manualy (write it) or regenerate designer.vb file it always disapear. How can I add it?

Comment: I have this issue sometimes. I delete the designer.vb file then right click the aspx file and select Convert to Web Application to auto generate the designer.vb file again. This normally does the job for me. If that fails. Reboot.

Comment: Are you copying and pasting that code? I've had that issue before doing that sometimes. What Mych suggested will probably work for you.

Comment: Yes, I do exactly that. Thanks for answers, it's okay now.